# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: not a valid ELF executable

Tags: android, android-studio, .so

**The error**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:761): not a valid ELF executable: /data/app-lib/com.yepstudio.android.nightclub-2/libgnustl_shared.so
```

The project was in eclipse.Now i have to use Android studio.
I keep the .jar and .so file in the $projectDir/libs.
And I add the code

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
```

[image]

But the error is still there

Comment: Do you compile the C/C++ code or do you simply add a `.so` file?

Comment: Just add .so file to libs.There is a Demo with the .so file and it is OK

Comment: It is wrong to add an already-compiled file to your project, because it is maybe built for other platforms (eg. built for win32, not linux)

Comment: The demo is OK.the demo is in the same platforms

Comment: I ever successed to make the project with the .so file in the eclipse.